# "The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers." in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I am facing this error on IIS. My site is in Perl CGI.
"The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers."

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. Can you at least show us what the perl script did output? Or if the script is small, post the script itself.

Comment: Its quite big file and it is combination more than 2 fiLES SO i AM NOT GETTING WHERE EXACTLY i AM GETTING THIS ERROR. When I write "print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";" line at the top then error dispopears but page is blank.

Comment: What server do you use? `Apache`, `IIS` or some other? Code samples could also help. And have a look at [Carp package](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) it allows outputting perl errors to html, which might be useful in development environments.

Comment: I am using IIS. cAN YOU TELL ME WHERE LOG FILES ARE GENERATED IN IIS?

Comment: `IIS` writes it's log messages to System Log. But you won't find perl errors there (at least when I had similar installation I was unable to see perl errors in logs). I advise you, don't use perl with `IIS`, it's a *major* headache. As for now, code samples and IIS perl handler declaration would help a lot.

Comment: Do you use CGI.pm or some framework?

Comment: I had this exact problem in Windows with Strawbery Perl and got  round it by adding these two lines: print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n";
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n\n";

Answer (score 4):

This means your program doesn't print headers, probably because your program doesn't compile

1. [You receive a "The specified CGI application misbehaved" error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145661)
2. [CGI Help Guide](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=165253)

Comment: yes exactly. My program doesn't print headers.

Comment: Can you suggest any solution?